# Back to Back Bar Chart with one common Y axis and two independent X values

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a back to back bar chart with State in the middle axis and two independent variables on either side.  Here is example data:

```
State   MedA    MedI
AK  0.056   46
AL  0.06    43
AR  0.052   39
AZ  0.055   20.5
CA  0.058   42
CO  0.0605  40
CT  0.06    29
DC  0.0625  47.5
DE  0.055   52
FL  0.057   55`
```

I used the below code to create two side by side charts, but I would like to combine so that state is the legend in the middle and MedA is on the left and MedI is on the right.

The other posts I checked seemed to require this to be done with a single variable on the x axis (such as gender) that had subgroups.

```
ga <- ggplot(state, aes(x=reorder(State, -MedA), y=MedA, fill=MedA)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  labs(x="State",y="Med A") +
  ggtitle("Median A by State") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+ 
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(hjust=1, vjust=0.5, size=5))+
  coord_flip()

gi<-ggplot(state, aes(x=reorder(State, -MedI), y=MedI, fill=MedI)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  labs(x="State",y="MedI") +
  ggtitle("Median I by State") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+ 
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(hjust=1, vjust=0.5, size=5))+
  coord_flip()

plot_grid(ga, gi,labels = "AUTO")
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have to play around with the figures and axis labels but this should work:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)

state<-data.frame(State=c("AK","AL","AR","AZ","CA","CO","CT","DC","DE","FL"),
                  MedA=c(0.056, 0.06, 0.052, 0.055, 0.058, 0.0605, 0.06, 0.0625, 0.055, 0.057),
                  MedI=c(46,43,39,20.5,42,40,29,47.5,52,55))

ga<-ggplot(state, aes(x=reorder(State, -MedA), y=MedA, fill=MedA)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  labs(x="State",y="Med A") +
  ggtitle("Median A by State") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
        legend.position="left",
        axis.text.y = element_text(hjust=1, vjust=0.5, size=5)
        )+
  coord_flip()+
  scale_y_reverse()+
  scale_x_discrete(position = "left")


gi<-ggplot(state, aes(x=reorder(State, -MedI), y=MedI, fill=MedI)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  labs(x="State",y="MedI") +
  ggtitle("Median I by State") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
        legend.position="left",
        axis.text.y = element_text(hjust=1, vjust=0.5, size=5)
        )+
  coord_flip()

plot_grid(ga, gi,labels = "AUTO")
```

[image]

Please note using the same colors for two different scales might be confusing.